# Error Deserializing JSON Array to List<T> C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

I'm attempting to deserialize a JSON Array, I have a node that receives a post request and spawns a C# child process, with the JSON Array passed in through a tmp file. When I attempt to deserialize the JSON array it throws this error:

```
Error: Command failed: dotnet OptiTools.dll "/tmp/tmp-1-FtT45M2y3swD"
Unhandled exception. Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "[ { "lat" : 38.904896, "lng" : -99.340191, "name" : "1"  }, { "lat" : 38.911362, "lng" : -99.354436, "name" : "2" }, { "lat" : 38.895442, "lng" : -99.318193, "name" : "3" }, { "lat" : 38.889632, "lng" : -99.318160, "name" : "4" }, { "lat" : 38.885637, "lng" : -99.320847, "name" : "5" }, { "lat" : 38.885635, "lng" : -99.321922, "name" : "6" }, { "lat" : 38.885781, "lng" : -99.333766, "name" : "7" }, { "lat" : 38.887466, "lng" : -99.339046, "name" : "8" }, { "lat" : 38.885649, "lng" : -99.336521, "name" : "9" }, { "lat" : 38.886740, "lng" : -99.352277, "name" : "10" }, { "lat" : 38.885956, "lng" : -99.324307, "name" : "11" }, { "lat" : 38.886353, "lng" : -99.323947, "name" : "12" }, { "lat" : 38.889276, "lng" : -99.319662, "name" : "13" }, { "lat" : 38.889065, "lng" : -99.319364, "name" : "14" }, { "lat" : 38.887511, "lng" : -99.319004, "name" : "15" }, { "lat" : 38.887947, "lng" : -99.320324, "name" : "16" }, { "lat" : 38.880091, "lng" : -99.317064, "name" : "17" }, { "lat" : 38.880365, "lng" : -99.317002, "name" : "18" }, { "lat" : 38.880087, "lng" : -99.315899, "name" : "19" }, { "lat" : 38.878123, "lng" : -99.314144, "name" : "20" }, { "lat" : 38.878123, "lng" : -99.315373, "name" : "21" }, { "lat" : 38.879612, "lng" : -99.315917, "name" : "22" }, { "lat" : 38.879633, "lng" : -99.317538, "name" : "23" }, { "lat" : 38.879511, "lng" : -99.318917, "name" : "24" }, { "lat" : 38.872725, "lng" : -99.317589, "name" : "25" }, { "lat" : 38.871773, "lng" : -99.316660, "name" : "26" }, { "lat" : 38.875437, "lng" : -99.317690, "name" : "27" }, { "lat" : 38.878437, "lng" : -99.317671, "name" : "28" }, { "lat" : 38.884577, "lng" : -99.317633, "name" : "29" }, { "lat" : 38.892398, "lng" : -99.321025, "name" : "31" }, { "lat" : 38.892897, "lng" : -99.324546, "name" : "32" }, { "lat" : 38.889882, "lng" : -99.333179, "name" : "33" }, { "lat" : 38.891063, "lng" : -99.333657, "name" : "34" }, { "lat" : 38.891065, "lng" : -99.333364, "name" : "35" }, { "lat" : 38.890792, "lng" : -99.333155, "name" : "36" }, { "lat" : 38.885620, "lng" : -99.334919, "name" : "37" }, { "lat" : 38.893812, "lng" : -99.336019, "name" : "38" }, { "lat" : 38.895593, "lng" : -99.332730, "name" : "39" }, { "lat" : 38.898277, "lng" : -99.335429, "name" : "40" }, { "lat" : 38.897998, "lng" : -99.331866, "name" : "41" }, { "lat" : 38.897998, "lng" : -99.333338, "name" : "42" }, { "lat" : 38.898068, "lng" : -99.332990, "name" : "43" }, { "lat" : 38.893207, "lng" : -99.328365, "name" : "44" }, { "lat" : 38.894332, "lng" : -99.333072, "name" : "45" }, { "lat" : 38.896496, "lng" : -99.331118, "name" : "46" }, { "lat" : 38.894145, "lng" : -99.327817, "name" : "47" }, { "lat" : 38.893864, "lng" : -99.327712, "name" : "48" }, { "lat" : 38.892924, "lng" : -99.327338, "name" : "49" }, { "lat" : 38.886863, "lng" : -99.327525, "name" : "50" }, { "lat" : 38.885832, "lng" : -99.325107, "name" : "51" }, { "lat" : 38.888653, "lng" : -99.326059, "name" : "52" }, { "lat" : 38.891872, "lng" : -99.324385, "name" : "53" }, { "lat" : 38.891696, "lng" : -99.323332, "name" : "54" }, { "lat" : 38.895412, "lng" : -99.320524, "name" : "55" }, { "lat" : 38.895387, "lng" : -99.323585, "name" : "56" }, { "lat" : 38.896950, "lng" : -99.326502, "name" : "57" }, { "lat" : 38.896957, "lng" : -99.323612, "name" : "58" }, { "lat" : 38.896700, "lng" : -99.320395, "name" : "59" }, { "lat" : 38.894557, "lng" : -99.320348, "name" : "60" }, { "lat" : 38.893441, "lng" : -99.323515, "name" : "61" }, { "lat" : 38.893441, "lng" : -99.323637, "name" : "62" }, { "lat" : 38.897367, "lng" : -99.327636, "name" : "63" }, { "lat" : 38.899215, "lng" : -99.327631, "name" : "64" }, { "lat" : 38.894731, "lng" : -99.331423, "name" : "65" }, { "lat" : 38.892939, "lng" : -99.330233, "name" : "66" }, { "lat" : 38.892921, "lng" : -99.330233, "name" : "67" }, { "lat" : 38.889079, "lng" : -99.330286, "name" : "68" }, { "lat" : 38.888606, "lng" : -99.330295, "name" : "69" }, { "lat" : 38.888508, "lng" : -99.331809, "name" : "70" }, { "lat" : 38.888655, "lng" : -99.329502, "name" : "71" }, { "lat" : 38.886589, "lng" : -99.317605, "name" : "72" }, { "lat" : 38.886589, "lng" : -99.317605, "name" : "73" }, { "lat" : 38.887620, "lng" : -99.317617, "name" : "74" }, { "lat" : 38.894740, "lng" : -99.317583, "name" : "75" }, { "lat" : 38.895597, "lng" : -99.317589, "name" : "76" }, { "lat" : 38.903833, "lng" : -99.317629, "name" : "77" }, { "lat" : 38.903859, "lng" : -99.317628, "name" : "78" }, { "lat" : 38.907180, "lng" : -99.319754, "name" : "79" }, { "lat" : 38.902268, "lng" : -99.317992, "name" : "80" }, { "lat" : 38.901969, "lng" : -99.317995, "name" : "82" }, { "lat" : 38.901969, "lng" : -99.317995, "name" : "83" }, { "lat" : 38.901969, "lng" : -99.317995, "name" : "84" }, { "lat" : 38.900166, "lng" : -99.306594, "name" : "86" }, { "lat" : 38.899893, "lng" : -99.313189, "name" : "87" }, { "lat" : 38.899877, "lng" : -99.315322, "name" : "88" }, { "lat" : 38.907873, "lng" : -99.315153, "name" : "89" }, { "lat" : 38.901351, "lng" : -99.321161, "name" : "90" }, { "lat" : 38.889548, "lng" : -99.317579, "name" : "91" } ] " to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OptiTools.Locations]'. Path '', line 1, position 5805.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OptiTools.Locations].
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.EnsureTypeAssignable(Object value, Type initialType, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.ConvertUtils.ConvertOrCast(Object initialValue, CultureInfo culture, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value)
   at OptiTools.JsonConverter.ExtractLoc(String jsonIn) in C:\Users\ryanb\Documents\Projects\Reoptimization\OptiTools\OptiTools\OptiTools\JsonConverter.cs:line 14
   at OptiTools.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\ryanb\Documents\Projects\Reoptimization\OptiTools\OptiTools\OptiTools\Program.cs:line 14
Aborted

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Socket.stream.socket.on (internal/child_process.js:346:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:567:12)
```

It appears to me that the JSON Array is correctly formatted to be deserialized to this list of Locations but for some reason can't cast. The Locations object is simple enough and shouldn't be the issue

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace OptiTools
{
    public class Locations
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And also here's the code for the class I made to convert the JSON:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Text;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace OptiTools
{
    public static class JsonConverter
    {
        public static List<Locations> ExtractLoc(string jsonIn)
        {
            List<Locations> locs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locations>>(jsonIn);
            return locs;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: nodeJS code:

```
// JavaScript source code
//const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const tmp = require('tmp');
const fs = require('fs');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 3000;

const cpro = require('child_process');
const file = 'OptiTools.dll';

var outp = "";



app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body.data));
    tmp.file(function createTmp(err, path, fd, cleanupCallback) {
        if (err) throw err;

        fs.writeFile(path, [JSON.stringify(req.body.data)], (err) => {
            if (err) { throw err } else {
                console.log(path)
                var runner = cpro.exec(`dotnet ${file} "${path}"`, { cwd: "../OptiTools/OptiTools/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1" }, (error, out, err) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    } else {
                        outp = out;
                        res.statusCode = 200;
                        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.send(outp);
                        cleanupCallback();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

the node logs this as the JSON:

```
"[ { \"lat\" : 38.904896, \"lng\" : -99.340191, \"name\" : \"1\"  }, { \"lat\" : 38.911362, \"lng\" : -99.354436, \"name\" : \"2\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.895442, \"lng\" : -99.318193, \"name\" : \"3\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.889632, \"lng\" : -99.318160, \"name\" : \"4\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.885637, \"lng\" : -99.320847, \"name\" : \"5\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.885635, \"lng\" : -99.321922, \"name\" : \"6\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.885781, \"lng\" : -99.333766, \"name\" : \"7\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.887466, \"lng\" : -99.339046, \"name\" : \"8\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.885649, \"lng\" : -99.336521, \"name\" : \"9\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.886740, \"lng\" : -99.352277, \"name\" : \"10\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.885956, \"lng\" : -99.324307, \"name\" : \"11\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.886353, \"lng\" : -99.323947, \"name\" : \"12\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.889276, \"lng\" : -99.319662, \"name\" : \"13\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.889065, \"lng\" : -99.319364, \"name\" : \"14\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.887511, \"lng\" : -99.319004, \"name\" : \"15\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.887947, \"lng\" : -99.320324, \"name\" : \"16\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.880091, \"lng\" : -99.317064, \"name\" : \"17\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.880365, \"lng\" : -99.317002, \"name\" : \"18\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.880087, \"lng\" : -99.315899, \"name\" : \"19\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.878123, \"lng\" : -99.314144, \"name\" : \"20\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.878123, \"lng\" : -99.315373, \"name\" : \"21\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.879612, \"lng\" : -99.315917, \"name\" : \"22\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.879633, \"lng\" : -99.317538, \"name\" : \"23\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.879511, \"lng\" : -99.318917, \"name\" : \"24\" }, { \"lat\" : 38.872725, \"lng\" : -99.317589, \"name\" : \"25\" } ] "
```

Comment: can you please post sample JSON that's failing

Comment: That JSON you have here (sneakily embedded in the error message rather than posted in the question) converts perfectly fine to the class you show here. There's something else you're not showing us.

Comment: It's included in the error message at the top on the second line it's quite long, but I can pretty print it and tack it onto the bottom if you wish

Comment: It's about making the question make sense. It's better to cut the code (and JSON) down to a minimum. Do you need 5000 characters of JSON to prove it's not working?  Just make a [mre]

Comment: also, not sure if that's an accurate copy of the raw json, or maybe it's a node or something that you've extracted

Comment: I put the same code as you have shown us with the same JSON File and it works fine, so as @DavidG says, there is something else missing.

Comment: I don't know what else it would be, one of the things it might be is the node receives x-www-urlencoded data then takes the JSON from the value and sends it to the child process, I can't add the nodeJS code as well if you want

Comment: My guess is that your JSON string is wrong and is double encoded. Check the raw string, is it surrounded by `"...."`? But if you don't show us the ACTUAL JSON then we can't help.

Comment: The error `Could not cast or convert from System.String to System.Collections.Generic.List``1[OptiTools.Locations]` suggests that DavidG is right.

Comment: I added some more information and what the node logs but I don't currently have a way to check the actual tmp file that is sent as it gets deleted

Comment: Sigh, we keep asking for a minimum and you now introduce NodeJS code.

Comment: Yeah, we're going to need to see the *actual* json that's being parsed. You'll have to write out your temp file or something. Both of those sample json's work just fine. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zyhp1o

Comment: It does look like you are calling `JSON.stringify` on a string that is already JSON though.

Comment: Look I'm sorry, this is the information I have to go off of, Someone mentioned that it might be a problem with node so I thought I might include it, I don't have a way to attach a debugger because of the environment its running in so can't get the actual JSON thats being passed in on that line, but I included what it was before and what its saying now I can rewrite my code and try to get the actual JSON on that line to be logged but its going to take a second

Comment: Okay thanks for that last problem @DavidG that was it, I changed that line and it works correctly, I appreciate the help, and I'm sorry if it got frustrated, I'm going to clean up the question some so its more readable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are double encoding the JSON in the NodeJS app. That means in the C# code, the JSON is a simple string so you could, in theory, decode it twice there:

```
var decodedJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(jsonIn);
List<Locations> locs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Locations>>(decodedJson);
```

Of course, that would be rather silly and a waste of resources. Instead, you should fix the NodeJS app so it doesn't double encode by removing the [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Comment: Breaking rules, but OMG THX THX THX, spend 5 hours of my life until you just saved me. :)